# am5 motherboard msi pro x670-p wifi not recognizing m.2 860 samsung ssd

Tags: amd-ryzen

I recently bought a new am5 motherboard and I can't manage to get my m.2 ssd working. But it can see my other sata drive. It had windows 11 before, maybe has something to do with the tpm 2.0 or something.
I tried between RAID and acpi neither worked. disabled secure boot and tpm. tried on every slot (it has 4). Maybe I'm just stupid and it doesnt work with m.2 ssd, but I couldn't find any info about this on the official documentation on the board. I wouldn't  upgrade to a nvme just yet, but i might have to.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Your M.2 860 ssd has a SATA interface. The M.2 slot on your motherboard is a PCIe interface with "Supports up to PCIe 4.0 x4" as the manual describes. Other AM5 motherboard manufacturers have added the supported speed in their description: "(64 Gb/s) mode" or "(128 Gb/s) mode"; they too do not mention SATA support.

I suggest to buy an adapter like a M2 SATA Adapter to 22-Pin SATA III for NGFF M.2 SATA-Based Key B / B+M.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).